# (Java) Saving/Loading an ArrayList using Properties

Tags: java, json, arraylist, collections, properties-file

I have been researching different methods for saving and loading configuration settings for my application.  I've looked into `Preferences`, `JSON`, `Properties` and XML but I think I've settled on using the `Properties` method for most of my application settings.

However, I'm not able to find any information on how to best save and load an ArrayList from that file.  It seems there are only individual key/pair string combinations possible.

So my question is basically, is there a better way to do this?  I have an `ArrayList` of Strings in my application that I need to be able to save and load.  Can this be done with `Properties` or do I need to use a separate file just to hold this list and then read it in as an `ArrayList` (per line, perhaps)?

**EDIT**: I should mention, I would like to keep all config files as readable text so I am avoiding using `Serialization`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using the following combination worked perfectly in my case.

**Save**:

```
String csv = String.join(",", arrayList());
props.setProperty("list", csv);
```

This will create a `String` containing each element of the `ArrayList`, separated with a comma.

**Load**:

```
arrayList = Arrays.asList(csv.split(","));
```

Takes the `csv` String and splits it at each comma, adding the elements to the `arrayList` reference.

Comment: that doesn't work for me, compiler says: 

"Incompatible types. Required ArrayList<String> but 'asList' was inferred to List<T>: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to ArrayList<String>

Comment: You need to specify the type of data being held in the `ArrayList.` The error message your received should make that clear. This method also only works on Strings, so you'll need to define your `ArrayList` as such:

`ArrayList<String> arrayList;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use commas to place multiple values on the same key.

```
key:value1,value2,value3
```

Then split them using the split function of a string after reading them in which will give you a `String[]` array which can be turned into an `ArrayList` via `Arrays.asList()`.

Here's a partial MCVE:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add("value1");
al.add("value2");
al.add("value3");

String values = al.toString();
//Substring used to get rid of "[" and "]" 
prop.setProperty("name",values.substring(1,values.length() - 1);
```

Comment: Sounds like a great solution for me!  Thank you.  Do you think you could post some sample code on how I would write the array to the `Properties` file with a delimiter?  I assume it would be some type of iteration through my array in the `setProperty()` method, right?

Comment: I would actually just create a representative `String` to pass.  I'll post up verified code in a second.

Comment: In the meantime, I'll try passing this `String` as the value: `String csv = String.join(",", arrayList)`.

Comment: Added how I would go about getting the comma separated list.

Comment: Why not use `al.toString()`?

Comment: @Clashsoft Thank you.  I didn't think that would work, I thought it would print memory location.

Comment: @Clashsoft that would return the string enclosed in brackets.  Not a big deal, but I'd then need to write code to remove them.  I found that `String.join()` works perfectly in my case.

Comment: @Zephyr My code already strips them.  I'm glad you found something that works though!

Comment: @SusannahPotts Ah, yes; it does!  I missed that.  I still think the code I just posted looks a little cleaner.  Do you know of any drawbacks for doing it with my method as opposed to yours?

Comment: @Zephyr I'd say yours is actually a tad better, in that it doesn't require specific character removal.  In regards to performance, I'd say the two are on par with each other.

Comment: @SusannahPotts Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen two approaches for writing lists to a `Properties` file. One is to store each element of the list as a separate entry by adding the index to the name of the property—something like `"mylist.1"`, `"mylist.2"`. The other is to make a single value of the elements, separated by a delimiter.

The advantage of the first method is that you can handle any value without worrying about what to do if the value contains the delimiter. The advantage of the second is that you can retrieve the whole list without iterating over all entries in the `Properties`.

In either case, you probably want to write a wrapper (or find a library) around the `Properties` object that adds methods to store and retrieve lists using whichever scheme you choose. Often these wrappers have methods to validate and convert other common data types, like numbers and URLs.